# Subclipse unable to commit: "Operation not permitted"

Tags: python, eclipse, subclipse

I installed SVN and have it running as a daemon (Ubuntu 11.04). I've successfully commited the repo from command line but anytime I try to commit through subclipse I get the following error:

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Operation not permitted
svn: Can't remove '/home/dave/share/workspace/project/.svn/tmp/entries'
svn: Can't remove file '/home/dave/share/workspace/project/.svn/tmp/entries': Operation not permitted

org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Operation not permitted
svn: Can't remove '/home/dave/share/workspace/project/.svn/tmp/entries'
svn: Can't remove file '/home/dave/share/workspace/project/.svn/tmp/entries': Operation not permitted
```

I tried recursively unsetting the sticky bit as I saw that was a fix on a thread a while back. I also switched my java within Eclipse > Team > SVN from JavaHL to SVNKit but that didn't work either. Anyone experience this before and can help?

Comment: So it turned out that using my virtual box (in which Ubuntu is running with a Win 7 host) shared directory was causing the issue. I created the project in Eclipse outside the shared folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please chekc the following scenarios

1) Could it be the case that the command line tool uses a newer version, than the SubClipse does?

2) Check whether you have update the latest trunk state, before you commit

3) Are you using the same user/password in subclipse than in the command tool

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the file is not in use. I use [Process Explorer](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653&rct=j&q=process%20explorer&ei=4g1KTvbXOKW0sQKt4qzrCA&usg=AFQjCNHyUurlTI_eszLaCHc9s3iGoXEojw&sig2=3-qycOUs2YDhYNVu5kiCew&cad=rja) to find if any programs have a handle on my files, but just logging out and in again (or restarting) also works as a brute-force approach if you don't mind the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug with VirtualBox shared folders. Apart from moving it outside the shared folder, another workaround it to use `git-svn` (install with `sudo apt-get install git-svn`, it doesn't come with standard `git`) to clone it automatically into a git repo.

Once `git-svn` is installed, you can use the command `git svn clone http://my-svn-repo local-folder` to clone a SVN repo without this error.